# Which version ubuntu works best on a Mac?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, 13.04

Disclaimer: New to this stuff

Hi,

I want to install ubuntu on my MacPro OSx Yosemite 2015. Do you have advice about which version is best to use?

Useful sources from which I can learn to operate Ubuntu ASAP are also very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: refer [here](https://forum.teksyndicate.com/t/ubuntu-on-macbook-pro-do-you-want-a-guide/78174) and [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-linux-macbook-pro/) .Also use LTS version [14.04 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases)

Comment: I suggest trying out the latest LTS version as Ravan suggest on a live CD or [USB stick(instructions here)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-os) before trying to install just to be sure it runs well on your machine before installing.  You could try other versions if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the specifications of the MacPro, you should find that the latest Long Term Support version 14.04, which can be gotten [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), works well.  Ravan suggested some good resources above for installation help.  I would also suggest the [Mac Installation wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation) on ubuntu.com as well.

As for resources to learn to use Ubuntu, you will find it very intuitive, but askubuntu.com is one of the best places to find specific information and answers to questions. [This tutorial](http://beginlinux.com/desktop/ubuntu) is a great place to get started though. (It refers to older versions, but the principles remain the same.)  [Another good tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-an-absolute-beginners-guide/).